# Show a div on hover of a different element and close it if mouse pointer is moved out of the div just showed

Tags: jquery, megamenu

I'm trying to create a mega menu and I would like to show it just on hover of a specific voice of the menu. Once the mega menu (div) is showed I would like to give the possibility to stay on it with the mouse (pointer) and close it once the pointer is moved out of the div.

This is my menu:

[image]

This is my menu when the mega menu is showed it is opened when you go over the "project" link:

[image]

At the moment I'm able to show the menu when I go over the "projects" link but I don't know how to close it when I move the mouse out of the Mega menu (div)

This is the code to show the menu:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#menu-item-15").hover(
        function(){
            jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").show();
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseover

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#menu-item-15").mouseover(
        function(){
            jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").show();
        }
    );

    jQuery("#menu-item-15").mouseout(
        function(){
            jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").hide();
        }
    );
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: This could work but in this way, I'm not able to navigate on the Mega menu because I'm not able to stay with the mouse on it. It is closed every time I move the mouse out from #menu-item-15 (the link to open the mega menu). Is there a way to keep #mega-menu-projects open as long as the pointer is moved out from #menu-item-15 and #mega-menu-projects (these div are attached as you can see from the image)

Answer (score 0):

Try This (not tested)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#menu-item-15" ).mouseout(function() {
        jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").hide();
    })
    .mouseover(function() {
        jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").show();
    });
});
```

Hope it's help you

Comment: I'm not able to stay/navigate on #mega-menu-projects div in this way. It is closed when I move the cursor out of #menu-item-15 div. Any advice to keep it open as long as I move the mouse out from the two divs? (the two divs are attached)